# if join returns false use other join at once. is it possable?

Tags: mysql

My code works not quite as i want:

```
SELECT
          r.id, 
          IF(exp.id != 0, 1,
            IF(exp2.id != 0, 1,
              IF(exp3.id != 0, 1, 0)
            )
          ) AS white_list

FROM rates AS r

LEFT JOIN
exclusion_policies    AS exp ON (
  1 = 1
  AND exp.client_id   = r.client_id
  AND exp.mcc         = r.mcc
  AND exp.mnc         = r.mnc
  AND exp.active      = 1
)
LEFT JOIN
exclusion_policies    AS exp2 ON (
  1 = 1
  AND exp2.client_id   = r.client_id
  AND exp2.mcc         = r.mcc
  AND exp2.active      = 1
)
LEFT JOIN
exclusion_policies    AS exp3 ON (
  1 = 1
  AND exp3.client_id   = r.client_id
  AND exp3.active      = 1
)
```

i want, if first join exp is true then stop verfy exp2 and exp3:
somethig like:

```
CASE WHEN 
  LEFT JOIN
    exclusion_policies    AS exp ON (
    1 = 1
    AND exp.client_id   = r.client_id
    AND exp.mcc         = r.mcc
    AND exp.mnc         = r.mnc
    AND exp.active      = 1
  )   
THEN true // exp is not null, ONLY
ELSE

  CASE WHEN 
    LEFT JOIN
      exclusion_policies    AS exp2 ON (
      1 = 1
      AND exp2.client_id   = r.client_id
      AND exp2.mcc         = r.mcc
      AND exp2.active      = 1
    )
    THEN true // exp2 is not null, ONLY
    ELSE

      CASE WHEN 
        LEFT JOIN
        exclusion_policies    AS exp3 ON (
        1 = 1
        AND exp3.client_id   = r.client_id
        AND exp3.active      = 1
      )
      THEN true // exp3 is not null, ONLY
      ELSE false // exp, exp2, exp3 are null
      END

  END
END
```

i need to get true(1), only one of third IF

```
IF(exp.id != 0, 1,
  IF(exp2.id != 0, 1,
    IF(exp3.id != 0, 1, 0)
  )
) AS white_list
```

by the way, maybe revers is more optimized LEFT JOIN exp3, 2 , 1, any way

Comment: Can you post table definitions and sample data please?

Answer (score 1):

You can create conditional join by putting correct logic in ON clause. Join will take place if ON criteria is true. Something like following code. I haven't tested it but you can givit it a try and post here again.

```
SELECT
   r.id, 
   IF(exp.id != 0, 1,
     IF(exp2.id != 0, 1,
       IF(exp3.id != 0, 1, 0)
     )
      ) AS white_list

FROM rates AS r
LEFT JOIN exclusion_policies AS exp ON 
       exp.client_id   = r.client_id AND 
       exp.mcc         = r.mcc AND 
       exp.mnc         = r.mnc AND 
       exp.active      = 1
LEFT JOIN exclusion_policies AS exp2 ON
       NOT (exp2.client_id   = r.client_id AND 
            exp2.mcc         = r.mcc AND 
            exp2.mnc         = r.mnc AND 
            exp2.active      = 1) AND 
       exp2.client_id   = r.client_id AND 
       exp2.mcc         = r.mcc AND 
       exp2.active      = 1
 LEFT JOIN exclusion_policies AS exp3 ON 
       NOT (exp3.client_id   = r.client_id AND 
            exp3.mcc         = r.mcc AND 
            exp3.mnc         = r.mnc AND 
            exp3.active      = 1) AND 
       NOT (exp3.client_id   = r.client_id AND 
            exp3.mcc         = r.mcc AND 
            exp3.active      = 1) AND 
       exp3.client_id   = r.client_id AND 
       exp3.active      = 1
```

Comment: intresting, but in any case i am getting true for white_list

Answer (score 0):

I sloved it,

thanks somebody

```js
IF(exp3.id != 0, 1,IF(exp2.id != 0, 1, IF(exp.id != 0, 1, 0))) 
FROM rates AS r
    LEFT JOIN
    exclusion_policies AS exp ON (
      exp.client_id       = r.client_id AND
      exp.mcc             = r.mcc AND
      exp.mnc             = r.mnc AND
      exp.active          = 1
    )
    LEFT JOIN
    exclusion_policies AS exp2 ON (
      exp2.client_id     = r.client_id AND
      exp2.mcc           = r.mcc AND
      exp2.mnc           IS NULL AND
      exp2.active        = 1
    )
    LEFT JOIN
    exclusion_policies AS exp3 ON (
      exp3.client_id     = r.client_id AND
      exp3.mcc           IS NULL AND
      exp3.mnc           IS NULL AND
      exp3.active        = 1
    )
```

Comment: Why make three tests when in the end you give `1` when the client ID is the same, no matter what? This is inefficient code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a `1` if any of the following is true:

- there is a record in `exclusion_policies` with the same `client_id`, `mcc`, `mnc` and `active = 1`, or
- there is a record in `exclusion_policies` with the same `client_id`, `mcc` and `active = 1`, or
- there is a record in `exclusion_policies` with the same `client_id` and `active = 1`.

But then you are actually saying you want a `1` when there is a record in `exclusion_policies` with the same `client_id` and `active = 1`. It seems unnecessary to even check on the more specific cases, because whether they are true or not does not influence the result based on the last check.

Put differently: this expression

```
IF(exp.id != 0, 1,
    IF(exp2.id != 0, 1,
        IF(exp3.id != 0, 1, 0)
    ) 
)
```

will only return 0 when, and only if, there is no record in `exclusion_policies` with the same `client_id` and `active = 1`

So you might as well execute this much simpler SQL statement:

```
SELECT    r.id,
          COALESCE(MAX(exp.active), 0) AS white_list
FROM      rates AS r
LEFT JOIN exclusion_policies AS exp 
       ON exp.client_id = r.client_id 
          exp.active    = 1
GROUP BY  r.id
```